# rawQuery sometimes doesn't find the item in the database (multi-threading issue)

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having an issue with `rawQuery`. Sometimes it doesn't find an item by its ID while other times it does.

My logic is as follows: I retrieve some data from a webservice. I sync it with the local database and then I return the response to the user from the local database (not from what I receive from the webservice).

My issue is that when I sync the data, the `rawQuery` retrieves the item from the local database to see if I already have it. If it can't find it, it inserts a new row, if it does, then it just updates it. Here's the method:

```
@Override
public ShopItem syncShop(ShopItem remoteShop) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = DbManager.instance().openDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
            DBContract.SHOPS.GET_SHOP_BY_REMOTE_ID,
            new String[]{String.valueOf(remoteShop.remote_id)});

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {//Item(s) exist
        ShopItem localShop = new ShopItem(c);
        if (localShop.updateDate == null || !localShop.updateDate.equals(remoteShop.updateDate)) {
            localShop.sync(remoteShop);

            db.update(DBContract.SHOPS.TABLE_NAME, localShop.getDbContentValues(),
                    DBContract.SHOPS.REMOTE_OBJ_ID + " = ?", new String[]{localShop.remote_id});
        }
        remoteShop = localShop;
    } else {//No item(s) found
        ContentValues values = remoteShop.getDbContentValues();
        long rowId = db.insert(DBContract.SHOPS.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        if (rowId != -1) {
            remoteShop.local_id = String.valueOf(rowId);
        }

    }
    free(db, c);
    return remoteShop;
}
```

I tried calling this method (just for debug purposes) 20 times in a row, in rapid succession and some of those times `c.moveToFirst()` is false, so it inserts a new item instead of updating it.

On the UI-thread, the 20 calls work properly, they don't create new items ... BUT I've recently moved the calls to the above method to non-UI threads and it's since then that it started acting up. I'm 100% positive it's an issue of multi-threading, but I can't figure out where the problem is.

Here's the `DbManager`

```
/*package*/ class DbManager {

private int mOpenCounter;

private static DbManager mInstance;
private static DbHelper mDatabaseHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

public static synchronized void initializeInstance(DbHelper helper) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new DbManager();
        mDatabaseHelper = helper;
    }
}

public static synchronized DbManager instance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(DbManager.class.getSimpleName() +
                " is not initialized, call initializeInstance(..) method first.");
    }

    return mInstance;
}

public synchronized SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
    mOpenCounter++;
    if (mOpenCounter == 1) {
        // Opening new database
        mDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    return mDatabase;
}

public synchronized void closeDatabase() {
    mOpenCounter--;
    if (mOpenCounter == 0) {
        // Closing database
        mDatabase.close();

    }
}
```

}

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should never use the same `SQLiteDatabase` object from multiple threads, because one connection can have only one transaction.

Furthermore, you must wrap the `query`/`update`/`insert` calls into a single transaction to prevent other threads from modifying the database in between.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. So it wasn't a multi-threading issue. Well, it was, but wasn't really.

I had this query:

```
    static final String GET_VISIT_BY_REMOTE_ID = "SELECT " + TABLE_NAME + ".*" + ", " +
            SHOPS.TABLE_NAME + "." + SHOPS.NAME + " AS " + SHOPS.TABLE_NAME + "_" + SHOPS.NAME +
            " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
            " INNER JOIN " + SHOPS.TABLE_NAME + " ON " + TABLE_NAME + "." + REMOTE_SHOP_ID + "=" + SHOPS.TABLE_NAME + "." + SHOPS.REMOTE_OBJ_ID +
            " WHERE " + TABLE_NAME + "." + REMOTE_OBJ_ID + " = ?";
```

The problem is is that while the above query was running, another query that synched the shops was running as well, in fact multiple queries. One that cleared the shops and one that synched the data back. So from time to time, even if the delete+sync_shop queries were immediately after one another, being in separate threads, the delete query would run first, then the above query (which didn't find shops, so the query failed, even if it had visits to return), and only then it repopulated the shops with data.

Basically I was deleting data, checking if it existed (from another thread) then populated the data, but it would be too late as the other thread finished already.